# How to optimize the high dimensional parameters in matrix factorization in Python?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy

I have a large sparse user-item matrix (`20,000` * `4000`), read from the user-item-rating data set:

```
        1    2    3    4    5 ....   4000
1       nan  nan  4    3    nan      nan
2       1    nan  nan  nan  nan      nan
3
...
20,000  2    3    nan  nan  nan      nan
```

(A `numpy` 2D array, with the `user-id` as row id and `item-id` as column id)

And I'd like to infer the user matrix and item matrix using `matrix factorization`. I tried `scipy.optimize` functions(BFGS, LBFGS, CG NEWTON, etc) (referenced to this [example](https://gist.github.com/macks22/00a17b1d374dfc267a9a))
 and all of them were killed in the training:

```
[1]    45535 killed     python pmf2.py
```

Could you please tell me how can I solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Be more specific about this `large sparse user-item matrix`.  How did you make it?  What's its type, shape, dtype?  `killed in the training` is also vague.

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry for that. I have edited the question and please take a look. Please tell me if other information is required.

Comment: Doesn't help. I don't know what you are showing us.  Is it a csv table, pandas table, scipy.sparse matrix, numpy array, or something else?  How are you using `scipy.optimize`?  The mention of `training` suggests the use `scikit_learning`.

Comment: @hpaulj The information is added. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/35577553/1461210